# Why does the second execution of my AsyncTask shows results "appended to" those from its first execution?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, callback

SO I have a SearchView in my Activity and when the user executes search by pressing the search button, an AsyncTask is executed by something like `new MyTask().execute();`.

In this MyTask, we consume a SOAP based web service, and the results of the SOAP call are returned from `doInBackground` of MyTask in the form of an ArrayList. This ArrayList is received as an argument in `onPostExecute` of MyTask, from where I have called-back to the Activity from which the AsyncTask was invoked:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<MyType> myList) {
   //****HERE I HAVE A CHECK WHICH PRINTS VALUES IN myList
  callingActivity.processResults(myList);//callingActivity is an object of the calling activity
}
```

`processResults` which is defined in the Activity from which this Task was executed, displays the results in a fragment.

***QUESTION***

The problem is that **when the user enters a new search query at this point, the new results retrieved appended to the previously received results.**

I had a check in `onPostExecute` which logs out (by `Log.i`) the values in the List, **and it confirms it that it is where the problem is. So why is this happening? Any pointers?**

---

***EDIT***

**Inside MainActivity.java:**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...

        searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.mainActivity_searchView);
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        handleIntent(getIntent());
    }

@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        setIntent(intent); // *************???? why do we do this ???
        if (searchResultsRecyclerViewFragment!=null && searchResultsRecyclerViewFragment.isVisible()) {getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(searchResultsRecyclerViewFragment).commit();
        } 
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH)) {
            String searchQuery = SearchManager.QUERY;
            performSearch(intent.getStringExtra(searchQuery));
        }
    }

private void performSearch(String searchQuery) {
        List<MyType> searchResultsList = new ArrayList<>();
new SearchTask(this, jBProgressIndicator).execute(params);
}

public void processResults(List<MyType> searchResultsList) {

        Bundle searchResultsBundle = new Bundle();
        searchResultsBundle.putSerializable("tests.test.SEARCH_RESULTS_BUNDLE_KEY", ((Serializable) searchResultsList));

        searchResultsRecyclerViewFragment = new SearchResultsRecyclerViewFragment();
        searchResultsRecyclerViewFragment.setArguments(searchResultsBundle);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.mainActivity_frameLayout, searchResultsRecyclerViewFragment);

        fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();//if I used commit(), EXCEPTION Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

    }
```

---

**EDIT 2**

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<MyType> list) {
        jbProgressIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        /**
         * check
         */
        Log.i(TAG, "________________________\n");
        for (MyType entry : list) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Name:> " + entry.getName() + "\n");
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "________________________\n");


        callingActivity.processResults(list);
    }
```

Comment: Without seeing the code it's difficult to answer...

Comment: What happens in callingActivity.processResults();

Comment: @Neo It basically adds a fragment and passes the list to the fragment as an argument. In the fragment (this fragment is also implementing LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks), we pass this list from arguments to a Loader while creating it, and the Loader simply returns this List in the `onLoadFinished` of `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks` implemented in that fragment. This `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks`; in this method, we create an `ArrayListAdapter` and pass this List to it during its creation.

Comment: @Neo Then we set this adapter for the recyclerview in this fragment, so the data is displayed in a recyclerview in the fragment.

Comment: @alfasin The real code is actually a lot. What parts of it should I post here?

Comment: I guess alfasin wants the same code... if not correct me :-)... the Adapter would be useful and how you set the new data / adapter to the ListView... please wait on alfasin, maybe he wants to see something else, so you don't need to post stuff twice

Comment: Agree with neo + I'd like to see what's going on inside `processResults()` and inside `processResults()` - after we'll look at this code we might ask for more...

Comment: @alfasin I posted some code. Is that enough?

Comment: @Solace sorry the second one was supposed to be `onPostExecute()`... (I accidently pasted the same thing twice)

Comment: @alfasin OK lemme show onPostExecute()

Comment: @Solace when the list reaches onPostExecute - does it already contain the duplicate data ?

Comment: @alfasin Yes, duplicate data from the previous search, and then new data from this search appended to it.

Comment: And what does `searchResultsList` contain when it enters `processResults()` ?

Comment: @alfasin The same...

Comment: That means you're looking in the wrong place :) see Laalto's answer - you should look into every assignment you have to `searchResultsList` - make sure to "clean" the list before you assign it with the new results!

Comment: What's the list that gets passed around in the asynctask?

Comment: @laalto It's the same list which is declared as a field in the class, initialized in `doInBackground` to contain the results of the SOAP call, then passed to `onPostExecute` in which it is passed to `processResults` of the calling Activity